# How to define DataDirectory for ConnectionString in console application to work with EntityFramework Code First Migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, app-config, localdb, datadirectory

I try to set location `MyProject\App_Data\Cos.mdf` for the database in `App.config`:

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Cos.mdf;Initial Catalog=Cos;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

In `Program.cs` I wrote:

```
 static void Main(string[] args) {

        string relative = @"..\..\App_Data\Cos.mdf";
        string absolute = Path.GetFullPath(relative);

        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", absolute); 
        Console.WriteLine(absolute);
        Console.ReadKey();
 }
```

The displayed path is(I paste it to show that I didn't make a mistake):

[image]

but then when I type in Package Manager Console `enable-migrations` change `AutomaticMigrations` to true, then type `update-database` I get error:

`Cannot attach the file 'C:\Users\s8359_000\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Projekt5 — kopia\Projekt5\bin\Debug\Cos.mdf' as database 'Cos'.`

Why does .NET tries to create my database in `Debug` directory?! I went through 15 subjects on StackOverflow on this topic and it looks like everybody just duplicates the answers which don't work.

**EDIT AFTER ANSWER OF SRUTZKY**
Yes you are right there is error. I tried few more combination after your answer, unfortunately none worked.

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\baza.mdf;Initial Catalog=baza;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

and the Main

```
  static void Main(string[] args) {

        Console.WriteLine("BEFORE:" + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory"));
        string relative = @"..\..\App_Data\Cos.mdf";
        string absolute = Path.GetFullPath(relative);
        absolute = Path.GetDirectoryName(@absolute);
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", @absolute);
        Console.WriteLine(@absolute);
        Console.WriteLine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory"));
        Console.ReadKey();
}
```

then I get in console:

[image]

and after deleting `Migrations` directory and `enable-migrations`, automatic migrations to true, `update-database` I get:

> PM> update-database Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL
>   statements being applied to the target database.
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A file activation
>   error occurred. The physical file name '\baza.mdf' may be incorrect.
>   Diagnose and correct additional errors, and retry the operation.
>   CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created.
>   Check related errors.    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String
>   methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout,
>   Boolean asyncWrite)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<NonQuery>b__0(DbCommand
>   t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget
>   target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext,
>   Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand
>   command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.<>c__DisplayClass1a.b__19(DbConnection
>   conn)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.<>c__DisplayClass33.b__32()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1
>   operation)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action
>   operation)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(DbConnection
>   sqlConnection, Action`1 act)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection
>   sqlConnection, Action`1 act)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.CreateDatabaseFromScript(Nullable`1
>   commandTimeout, DbConnection sqlConnection, String
>   createDatabaseScript)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection
>   connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection
>   storeItemCollection)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateDatabase(DbConnection
>   connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection
>   storeItemCollection)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateDatabase()    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DatabaseCreator.Create(DbConnection
>   connection)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action
>   mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action
>   mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String
>   targetMigration)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String
>   targetMigration)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.Run() 
>   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate
>   callBackDelegate)    at
>   System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner
>   runner)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String
>   targetMigration, Boolean force)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action
>   command) ClientConnectionId:23ca49c1-4797-4bc3-8f16-f34fd77f2cbe A
>   file activation error occurred. The physical file name '\baza.mdf' may
>   be incorrect. Diagnose and correct additional errors, and retry the
>   operation. CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be
>   created. Check related errors. PM>

Comment: Not sure that the Package Manager could read your code, compile it, run it and determine that you have set another value for DataDirectory. It is a console application so I think it expects the database in that location.

Comment: @Steve Before invocation of `SetData` the `Console.WriteLine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory"));` printed empty string, after SetData it, it printed the correct string:`'C:\Users\s8359_000\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Projekt5 — kopia\Projekt5\App_Data\Cos.mdf'`

Comment: @Steve PackageManagerConsole probably sees my code because if I didn't use `SetData` method, `update-database` would create database in `C:\Users\s8359_000\DATABASEFILE.mdf`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Problem 1 (of 2)

When you set the value of `DataDirectory`, it needs to be a directory, not a file. You are passing in the value of the `absolute` variable which is:

```
C:\Users\s8359_000\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Projekt5 — kopia\Projekt5\App_Data\Cos.mdf
```

and which contains the filename. That is not valid. `DataDirectory` is a substitution value, so specifying:

```
AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Cos.mdf
```

in the connection string would translate into:

```
C:\Users\s8359_000\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Projekt5 — kopia\Projekt5\App_Data\Cos.mdf\Cos.mdf
```

That is not a valid path. So it appears that .NET sees that the value of `DataDirectory` is not valid and does not use it and hence starts in the current working directory.

Use `Path.GetDirectoryName(relative)` instead of `Path.GetFullPath(relative)` to set the value of `absolute` and it should work as it will set the value of `DataDirectory` to be:

```
C:\Users\s8359_000\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Projekt5 — kopia\Projekt5\App_Data
```

The MSDN page for [Connection Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716756.aspx) has some additional details towards the bottom, in the section titled, "Support for the |DataDirectory| Substitution String..."

### Problem 2 (of 2)

1. "DataDirectory" is set in the AppDomain.
2. Console Apps have their own AppDomains that are created when they start and go away when they exit.
3. Package Manager (where you are running `Update-Database`) does not have access to the AppDomain of your console app where you are setting the value of "DataDirectory".
4. You need to either:

   1. programatically set "DataDirectory" in Package Manager, or
   2. programatically run "update-database" within the context of your console app

I don't know how to programatically interact with Package Manager, but I did manage to figure out how to programatically fire the "update-database" process. Just add the following line just after you set the value of "DataDirectory":

```cs
Database.SetInitializer(new
    MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<YourDataContextName, Configuration>()
 );
```

You will also need at least one, if not two, `using` statements:

- `using System.Data.Entity;`
- `using ProjectName.Migrations; // namespace of Migrations\Configuration.cs`

Please note that this alone does not create the database. Any pending changes will be published when you first *access* the database via the DbContext.

Example:

```cs
using System.Data.Entity;
using Projekt5.Migrations;

....

string relative = @"..\..\App_Data\Cos.mdf";
string absolute = Path.GetDirectoryName(absolute);
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", absolute);
Database.SetInitializer(new
    MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<Projekt5Context, Configuration>()
 );
// database not created yet

using (var db = new Projekt5Context())
{
  db.Things.Add(new Thing { Name = "OMG This works!" });
  db.SaveChanges();
} 
// database CREATED!
```

Also, you *might* need to call the following, one time, via Package Manager (it doesn't do anything immediately to the database so the connection string is not accessed):

```
Add-Migration InitialMigration
```

For more info, please see the MSDN page for [Code First Migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx).

Once this line of code to call `SetInitializer` is there with `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`, it does just that: each time it runs (which is why this is done at the beginning of the console app) it syncs any changes between what is in the "model" (that is now compiled into the Assembly) and the database, making sure that the database has the latest version. This assumes that any new tables are represented in the `DbContext` class. But no additional Package Manager commands need to be ran.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this mistake of mine, I tried exactly what you have said then few more combinations and I posted results in the edit to the original post.

Comment: @yoda I won't have time until later today to play with this, but just wondering if you need "\\" instead of "\" in the connection string (i.e. "\\baza.mdf"). Another thing: I would, for now, remove "|DataDirectory|" and use hardcoded full path until this works and then try getting "|DataDirectory|" to work.

Comment: Hardcoded full path works, I checked it before I posted this question on SO. This is general problem to which I am looking for a solution(for future).

Comment: It worked. The last question, so now I can't use update-database inside Package Manager Console but if I want to update to current model just run application debugging?

Comment: @Yoda I have tested and added a final paragraph to my answer. All changes are synced each time you run the console app. No need to do anything in Package Manager.

Answer (score 10):

You can set DataDirectory for Update-Database in Configuration class which was created by Enable-Migrations command:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<DataContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        var dataDirPath = "<YourPath>";
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", dataDirPath);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are a genius!  This is the only answer that lets me run "Update-Database" from the Package Manager Console.

Comment: Simple and elegant solution! Bravo!

Answer (score 5):

To point the DataDirectory to a folder named 'AppData' under the console project and EF code first migrations you must do the following:

```
public static class AppData
{
    public static void Set()
    {
        // Set the |DataDirectory| path used in connection strings to point to the correct directory for console app and migrations
        var baseDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        string relative = @"..\..\App_Data\";
        string absolute = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(baseDirectory, relative));
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", absolute);
    }
}
```

Then call `AppData.Set()` from the entry point of the console application and database migrations:

1) Console application's Main-method or Startup-class:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
         AppData.Set();
    }
}
```

2) EF code first migrations

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    // Add this constructor to your database context
    public DatabaseContext() : base()
    {
        AppData.Set();
    }

    // DbSet's are defined here
}
```

Comment: This solution allows me to enable-migrations in the first place. Before enabling migrations, the context exists, whereas the configuration class doesn't. So Rasul's solution cannot be used initially, when enabling migrations for the project. However, when using update-database, the DataDirectory in the AppDomain must be set in the Configuration constructor as per Rasul's answer. Since the BaseDirectory is correct at that time as well, you simply add the same line of code: AppData.Set();