# Connecting to Db after upgrading to .net

Tags: entity-framework, connection-string, .net-5, localdb

I write a WPF program which uses LocalDb. The program worked perfectly with `|DataDirectory|`.

```
        var sqlConnectionStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            DataSource = @"(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB",
            AttachDBFilename = $"|DataDirectory|\\Lc Db {userName}.mdf",
            IntegratedSecurity = true
        };
```

I upgraded from .net46 to .net5 but I still use EF and not EF.Core. Now I got this exception when reaching for the db at the first time: `Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'`. If I use absolute path then I can reach the Db.

```
        var sqlConnectionStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            DataSource = @"(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB",
            AttachDBFilename = $"AttachDBFilename = @"c:\Users\xyz\Documents\LedgerCommander\LedgerCommander\bin\Debug\net5.0-windows\Lc Db Heckl.mdf"",
            IntegratedSecurity = true
        };
```

How should I use `|DataDirectory|` in .net core? I tried a number of approach without success. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12187068/where-is-datadirectory-defined), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27730546/how-to-define-datadirectory-for-connectionstring-in-console-application-to-work), [3](https://kontext.tech/column/dotnet_framework/279/set-attachdbfilename-as-relative-path-in-net-core), [4](https://www.buzzphp.com/posts/cant-connect-to-localdb-when-using-datadirectory-in-windows-forms-c-sharp-ne)

Comment: Maybe you can try ErikEJ.EntityFramework.SqlServer which uses Microsoft.Data.SqlClient ?

Comment: Thanks @ErikEJ  I installed the nuget, changed the using, added the attribute to the dbContext. Now there is an error "The type 'SqlFunctions' exists in both 'EntityFramework.SqlServer, and 'ErikEJ.EntityFramework.SqlServer". I thought I should remove the nuget EntityFramework.SqlServer but actually there is no such nuget only the EntityFramework. Any idea?

Comment: Interesting, can you share how you are using SqlFunctions on Github?

Comment: Dear @ErikEJ   Here is the [link](https://github.com/heckl/learn-git.git).  I created a method to replace a Db view. As I understand this compile error means that `SqlFunctions` is now in two assemblies. I tried to remove the old assembly using solution explorer.

Comment: Most likely a bug, will investigate

Comment: I have published an updated Nuget package with a fix for this, you have to rename SqlFunctions => MicrosoftSqlFunctions with the new package

Comment: Thank you @ErikEJ   I had to select the prerelease to install the latest version but now the compile time error is gone. Unfortunately, this did not help with the original issue. I still have the exception if `DataDirectory` is used. What is strange that the exception also says that the source is still `System.Data.SqlClient`.

Comment: Check the readme, update your using!

Comment: Dear @ErikEJ   I have already set the attribute `DbConfigurationType` before the  `dbContext`. Called `DbProviderFactories.RegisterFactory`, changed to `using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;` Still I have the exception from `System.Data.SqlClient`.

Comment: Please post an issue on Github with repro, and let us stop the discussion here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [PureManApplicationDevelopment](https://github.com/derskythe/WpfSettings) can determine the DataDirectory. In the constructor change `_DataDir = string.Empty;` to `_DataDir = _CurrentPath;` Then you can create the connection string.

```
            var dataDirectory = PureManApplicationDeployment.DataDirectory;
            var sqlConnectionStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
            {
                DataSource = @"(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB",
                //AttachDBFilename = $"|DataDirectory|\\Lc Db {userName}.mdf",
                AttachDBFilename = $"{dataDirectory}Lc Db {userName}.mdf",
                IntegratedSecurity = true
            };
```